# jQuery Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the way I handle an Ajax response. I am sure it can be improved.

```
success: function (json) {                  
                $.each(json, function(index,item){              
                    if (item.field == "article_id") {
                        $("#article_id").val(item.value);
                    } else if (item.field == "naslov") {
                        $("#naslov").val(stripslashes(item.value));
                    }else if (item.field == "slug_naslov") {
                        $("#slug_naslov").val(item.value);
                    }else if (item.field == "datum") {
                        $("#datum").val(item.value);
                    }else if (item.field == "url") {
                        $("#url").val(item.value);
                    }else if (item.field == "tekst") {
                        $("#tekst").val(stripslashes(item.value));
                    }else if  (item.field == "tag_title") { //handle tags - tokeninput                          
                        var tagoviArray = item.value;                       
                        var tagoviInput = $("#txtTags");    
                            $(tagoviInput).tokenInput("clear");
                            $.each(tagoviArray, function (index, value) {                           
                                var arr = value.split(','); 
                                    $.each(arr, function (i, v) {   
                                        if (!(v=="")) { 
                                            $(tagoviInput).tokenInput("add", {id: "", name: v}); tag
                                        }
                                    });                         
                            });

                    }else if (item.field == "love") {
                        $("#love").val(item.value);
                    }          
                });
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
success: function (json) {
  var decorators = {},
      handlers = {};

  // decorators prepare content for insertion
  decorators.naslov = stripslashes;
  decorators.tekst  = stripslashes;

  // specialized handlers
  handlers.tag_title = function (value) {
    // do the tokenization-stuff here
  };

  // Go through the response
  $.each(json, function (index, item) {
    var value = item.value;
    // if the field has its own handler, use that
    if( typeof handlers[item.field] === "function" ) {
      handlers[item.field](value);
    } else {
      // Otherwise, send the value through the decorator
      // (if there is one for the given field), and
      // insert the value in the corresponding input
      if( typeof decorators[item.field] === 'function' ) {
        value = decorators[item.field](value);
      }
      $("#" + item.field).val(value);
    }
  });
}
```